# How to use angularJS with mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have stored tweets with "BYE" keyword from twitter in mongoDB.Now I need to built a single web page with search text box where I can search these tweets using angularJS.

Edit : I dont want to use any middleware.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to serve the data using one of java, c#, node, python blah blah blah.

Probably your best choice is an MVC framework of some sort that will facilitate producing the data in a restful manner. Language up to you ... (just not php ;-))

For example spring-mvc for java, .net mvc for c#.

Comment: +1 about php ))) node + express + mongoose will be best choice I think

Comment: without using any middleware,is it possible..like using rest or something?

Comment: some databases like couchdb have a direct REST API. However, there exist some layers for mongoBD so you dont have to do much by yourself... http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces//

Answer (score 0):

I did by using [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch).Elasticsearch uses standard RESTful APIs and JSON.It can be used with javascript also. Configure mongodb and elasticsearch using this [link](http://www.codetweet.com/ubuntu-2/configuring-elasticsearch-mongodb/) (this blog post quite old).